# Creating Object with variable as a key and value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am learning react and I am following the [quick start guide](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html), In the topic [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) I found the Calculator component

```
class Calculator extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      ...

      this.state = {scale: 'c', temperature: ''}
    }

    handleCelsiusChange(temperature) {
      this.setState({scale: 'c', temperature})
    }

    handleFahrenheitChange(temperature) {
      this.setState({scale: 'f', temperature});
    }

    render() {
      ...

      return (
        <div>
          ...
        </div>
      )
    }
  }
```

My question is about this sentence `this.setState({scale: 'c', temperature})` here I am expecting `this.setState({scale: 'c', temperature: temperature})`.

Is this `temperature` assignation some react sintax sugar? Could you please explain me why this works.

Thanks

Comment: Note this has nothing to do with `setState()`. This is syntax for the object literal as described in the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`{scale: 'f', temperature}` is basically a `Property value shorthand` syntax for `{scale: 'f', temperature: temperature}`,

So in JavaScript with `ES6/ES2015`, if you want to define an object who's keys have the same name as the variables passed-in as properties, you can use the shorthand and simply pass the key name.

Check this **[doc](https://javascript.info/object#property-value-shorthand)** for the details

An important thing to note while using this syntax is, the JS engine looks in the containing scope for a variable with the same name.

If it is found, that variable’s value is assigned to the property.

If it is not found, a `ReferenceError` is thrown. It’s worth noting that the `transpilers` will not throw an error at compile time if the variable is not found, but instead will declare an object with the name of the not-found variable.

However, when the code runs you will still get the `ReferenceError` since the variable does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

This is some javascript syntax sugar.

It's a pretty common case to do something along the lines of:

```
const obj = {
    a: a,
    b: b,
    c: c
};
```

where you are building an object out of variable you already have and keeping their same names. But you'll notice that you're having to write each variable name twice. So instead, you can write:

```
const obj = { a, b, c };
```

and it will be evaluated the same as the above code.